# How can I align a piece of text by the right side on a post?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, formatting

I have a quote:

> "Like this."

I want to place its source signature on the right side of the post.

I have tried `<span style="text-align:right;"> -The Author </span>`, but that does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure, but probably RtL marker could do it (not that I endorsed this, though)

Comment: You don't. Markdown as used on Stack Overflow has very limited formatting capabilities. In my personal opinion that's a feature :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I did add the 'feature-request' tag on the post; thanks for the comment.

Comment: [Related Answer or Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407341/4575793)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only element that currently supports specifying text alignment is a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables), with the use of the `:` character in the separator row to indicate alignment direction.

As a header row is [currently required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357093/349071), the simplest forms of a table with right-aligned text would look like:

```md
|table with header only|
|-:|
```

| table with header only |
| --- |

Or:

```md
||
|-:|
|table with a single row|
```

|  |
| --- |
| table with a single row |

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's important to have this in Stack Overflow. You can simply mention the author before or after the quote, without having their name on the right. For example:

---

I'm quoting [sitename](http://possiblelink.com):

> Like this

<strike>Another (alternative is using code-block formation instead of quoting:</strike>

```
Like this
             - sitename
```

---

However, if you insist to do that (I don't like this solution, but it's the best I can think of), you can add the EM SPACE (`&emsp;`) character (one character = one space):

> I'm Maroun
>                                                                                     - Maroun Maroun

<sup>I'm not HTML expert, I don't know how this will be handled by different browsers/devices, so I'm not sure if it's a good way of adding a space when having limited formatting capabilities</sup>

Comment: Don't ___ever___ use code blocks for quotes. Only use code blocks for ___code___.

Comment: Interesting workaround with the code-block; it looks very similar on here (meta) however on stackoverflow it wouldn't look like an external reference quote (which is yellow);

Comment: @Cerbrus Apart from being ugly (and I agree it is), why shouldn't it be used?

Comment: It's semantically incorrect and it hurts readability.

Comment: @Cerbrus True. Edited.