# Text aligned right and left in the same line

Tags: support, markdown

I'm almost certain that I've seen some post in the Q&A that had, in the same line, some text aligned to the right and some text aligned to the left, kind of like a page header.

I've been looking through the markdown help pages and posts but I'm not being able to find anything, the most I could find was how to align text to the right in a table, but that's all the text, and I would also forego the table.

How is it done?

Comment: @Anonymous Why? They're seeking support, there's no subjective answer or discussion to be had

Comment: You should've saved a link or two :) Or have you?

Comment: @OlegValter not all, the help ones for sure https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#headers and https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Comment: @anastaciu - no, I mean the posts, of course :)

Comment: One coud always make a table with 2 columns and aling one to the right and another to the left (I think that can be done), but I'm sure I've seen this in plain header text.

Comment: @anastaciu - no worries :) Just curious - not sure if this is possible (apart from obvious spaces of different widths - but those would obviously wrap depending on the screen size)

Comment: @OlegValter so far it seems you're right, let's wait, maybe someone appears with a magic trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tables?

| ## left | ## right |
| --- | --- |

```
| <h1>left</h1> | <h1>right</h1> |
| :------------ | -------------: |
```

Comment: Exactly like this, now... can you remove the table ;)

Comment: Here it is, the fruit of your work https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361247/6865932, still think it would look nicer without the table though.

Comment: What are you talking about, no apologies needed, yours is a great answer, I was just wondering if it's possible, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

## Like                                                                     this?

```
Like &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp; this?
```

Comment: Exactly, just [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpryU.png) :)

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah didn't expect it to scale well on smaller screens. Fitting one line on full size page

Comment: I know, I had to resize the window to do that :) I think there is no way there could be an in-post responsive title

Comment: @charlietfl, that's the workaround, may it's what I saw, like when people see a bear and think it's a yeti ;)

Answer (score -9):

You can also use flex layout with `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Left text</span><span>Right text</span></h1>
```

Comment: ehm, I think the question asks about how somebody could achieve this *in the body* of a post, not as a runnable snippet...

Comment: The programming questions shouldn't be asked on meta and at the same time the snippets are supported on meta. Funny.

Comment: @Sinatr - hey they are cool for prototyping a proposed feature or making a runnable demo of why one thinks the same feature is a horrible idea :)

Comment: seems like you are at the wrong place, this is MetaStackoverflow not stackoverflow